# Best way to bind several columns of a dataframe by row in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe which has the following form

```
ID1 | VALUE |ID2 | VALUE | ID3 | VALUE
111  | one   |333 | three | 555 | five
222  | two   |    | NA    | 666 | six
```

Note that the number of values/rows in each column varies (NAs/empty values).

I want the result to look like this:

```
ID  | VALUE 
111 | one
222 | two
333 | three
555 | five
666 | six
```

I tried the following:

```
x = as.matrix(df)
x= matrix(x,ncol = 2)
```

This process mixes IDs and VALUEs for some columns. My guess is that this is because of NA and NULL values.

```
ID  | VALUE 
111 | one
222 | two
333 | three
five| 555
six | 666
```

Could you please suggest a quick solution(s) to my problem?

**Elegant Solutions**

Thanks to [nongkrong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2415684/nongkrong) and [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) for answers.
I don't know about speed, but the most elegant solutions that got the job done are the following:

- `my_final = data.frame(VALUE=unlist(my_data[c(TRUE,FALSE)]), ID=unlist(my_data[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))`
- `my_final = setNames(data.frame(lapply(split(as.list(my_data), c(F, T)), unlist)), c("VALUE", "ID"))`

Also to omit empty rows:

- `my_final_trimmed = my_final[complete.cases(my_final), ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another base R, using `split` to separate alternating columns

```
res <- setNames(
    data.frame(lapply(split(as.list(dat), c(F, T)), unlist))
  , c("VALUE", "ID"))

res[complete.cases(res), ]
#      VALUE      ID
# ID11   111  one   
# ID12   222  two   
# ID21   333  three 
# ID31   555    five
# ID32   666     six
```

Comment: That is a nice option with `split`.  I was thinking about `data.frame(VALUE=unlist(df1[c(TRUE,FALSE)]), ID=unlist(df1[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))`

Comment: @akrun nice! I was thinking similarly, but I'm all about `split` right now

Comment: It worked  perfectly on my dataframe (over 500000 rows). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One option is using `melt` from the devel version of `data.table`.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Using `melt`, we specify the `measure` argument with `regex` `patterns` of column names that start with 'ID' and 'VALUE'.  Optional arguments include naming the 'value' columns i.e. `value.name` and removing the `NA` values with `na.rm=TRUE`.   If we don't need the 'variable' column, it can be assigned (`:=`) to NULL.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
melt(setDT(df1), measure= patterns("^ID", "^VALUE"), 
   value.name= c("ID", "VALUE"), na.rm=TRUE)[,variable:=NULL][]
#   ID VALUE
#1: 111   one
#2: 222   two
#3: 333 three
#4: 555  five
#5: 666   six
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID1 = c(111L, 222L), VALUE = c("one", "two"), 
ID2 = c(333L, NA), VALUE.1 = c("three", NA), ID3 = c(555L, 
666L), VALUE.2 = c("five", "six")), .Names = c("ID1", "VALUE", 
"ID2", "VALUE.1", "ID3", "VALUE.2"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, sorry if this answer is too specific for your case, but taking the data frame in that form, the answer is approachable (inelegantly) as follows:

1) annihilate column names

```
colnames(dataframe_name) <- NULL
```

2) split into smaller data frames by subsetting

```
df1 <- dataframe_name[, 1:2]  # columns 1-2
df2 <- dataframe_name[, 3:4]  # columns 3-4
df3 <- dataframe_name[, 5:6]  # columns 5-6
```

3) add column names to the data frames

```
f <- function(df) {
    colnames(df) <- c('ID', 'VALUE')  # set colnames for df with 2 cols
    return(df)
} # function to apply to each df

l <- list(df1, df2, df3)
list_of_frames <- lapply(l, f)  # apply colname function to each
```

4) bind the data frames together

```
do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)  # call rbind (row bind) on each frame
```